# Citrix ICA client (64 bits, Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, citrix

To access applications remotely I need to install the "Citrix ICA client". That seems simple, until you're confronted with the Citrix Downloads webpage:

http://www.citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/index.asp

Which version do I need?

Comment: Do you want to access a citrix Server/farm from lan or from wan (internet). Web-Access needs some different configuration

Comment: You have to use CitrixReceiver.
[citrix-receiver](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the Citrix XenApp online plug-in:

http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/legacy-client-software/online-plug-in-123.html

Comment: It's working now.